# how to compare group of sets to a set of number for closets pair

Tags: statistics

I want to see the closest match for a group of number sets to a particular set.

Set A [.2, .5632, -1.235, -.0655,....]

setArray(0[1.235, 3.32, .32, -.6....], 1[.256, .23, -.56, ......])

I want to see which set in the array is the closest match to Set A.

I looked it up on web search, and I found Student T-Test but got lost on the math. It said to take p-value, etc and calculates it on a calculator. I need each step so I can use it in a spreadsheet.

Can someone show me how I do this comparative study, in simple math. I am zero in math and the sigma, alpha signs I can't understand.

Thanks you for you time!

Edit;

What I am trying to do is find the closest stock beta to an index. I am taking the daily `closePrice/previousClose -1` for Index and some stocks. I want to see over a period of time which stock moves most closely to the Index.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you defining "closest match"?  Are your sets ordered?

Comment: updated the question to give more clarity on question

Comment: My questions remain:  How are you defining "closest match"?  Are your sets ordered?  I am guessing from your edit that these are time series (which would imply that they are ordered, yes?).  But why make your readers guess what you mean?

Comment: @lulu, sorry about that. it is a time series data. By closest match I mean, over time which stock represents the closest move to the Index. Each data point is a percent move of price compared to previous day.

Comment: "closest" requires the choice of a metric.  If you have one in mind, why not simply compute all the distances and select the minimum?  I don't think it's obvious which choice to make, but of course a standard choice is just the usual Euclidean distance, $d(\vec x, \vec y)=\sqrt {(x_1-y_1)^2+\cdots +(x_n-y_n)^2}$

Comment: Thank you. By Euclidean Distance method, the number closest to zero will be the best match?

Comment: I need to find directional match too. by this method if it moves in the opposite direction by the same amount, i think i will get the same result as a stock that moves in the same direction by same amount

Comment: As I have said, you need to define what you mean by "closest".  Nobody can do that for you.